# j2me supports android phones

Tags: java-me

I done mobile application in j2me platform. Tested successfully in Symbian os mobiles ..like nokia,samsung..sony ericsson. I have doubt in j2me supports android and blackberry mobiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run j2me application on Android with little effort, but user experience is not that of "native" android applications. So if possible, rewrite the application for Android SDK. This is not that hard, though many parts of code will need to be rewritten or rearranged.